# Dynamic fields passed in Resource

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-import-export

I'm trying to handle dynamic CSV, meaning I have no control over the format of the headers so my Idea is the frontend will parse the CSV first get the headers and pass it along with the file. So my question how should I handle dynamic fields using django-import-export?

Comment: I expect you'll have to write some kind of translation logic to go from the dynamic fields to 'named' fields for django-import-export to work.  django-import-export is not going to be able to handle the concept of dynamic fields. [tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) docs may help you understand this problem better

Comment: hmm. I'll check I was thinking of passing it to the resource once initialized but I might be wrong in thinking that.